# Custum default input value in laravel view template

Tags: php, html, laravel, input, laravel-blade

I want to add a default text and then the input value from database. my view code looks like this:

```
{{ Form::label('url', 'Update your youtube video url:') }}
{{ Form::text('url', null, ["class" => 'form-control input-lg']) }}
```

it looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKJgR.png)

But I want to show like this: *"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="*"here input from database"
So, How can I add my own text before input value from database?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
{{ Form::text('url', $url, ["class" => 'form-control input-lg']) }}
```

from your controller pass $url

```
$url = 'Some default url';
return View::make('layout.name')->with('url', $url)
```

Comment: It doesn't work like this. If i use ur way, then it only shows my default url & input value from database vanished. But I want to show my "defalut url"+"value from database".

Comment: you can concatenate your default url and db value in $url variable. $url = "default" + $db_url;

Comment: Thanks, it works. So simple logic. But my brain went blank.